# Javascript regular expression to sanitize string with pipes

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a little help in trying to sanitize a string. I have written a regular expression that is pretty close to giving me the results I want but I just can't quite get it right. The string I'm receiving is in this format.
`||a|assa||asss||ssss`
The pipe character are basically placeholders to what would have been a separator for text. However, I'm trying to end up with something that would look like this.
`|a|b|c|d` in other words I'm just trying to remove consecutive pipes. I have put together a little example to illustrate what I have attempted and keep failing miserably.

```js
const str1 = "||a||jump|fences||in the street";
const str2 = "im a wolf";
const hasPipe = /\|{1}\+/;//if the | is consecutevely repeated more than once than deleted.

console.log(hasPipe.test(str1));
console.log(str1.replace(hasPipe, ""))
console.log(hasPipe.test(str2));
```

The expected result to the above code should simply be.
`|a|jump|fences|in the street"`
Can someone please point me in the right direction or point my silly mistake.

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding regex.  To repeat, you just want `+`.

Comment: I'm pretty certain I've tried that variation and was not able to get the results correctly. I'll give it another shot. so should it be these ? `/\|\+/` because that does not seem to work?

Comment: Why are you escaping the `+`? Read the documentation and learn how regex works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your test string `const str1 = "||a||jump|fences||in the street";` you want to replace multiple occurrences of *pipe* `|` with a single pipe.

There are a couple of ways to match a non-empty sequence:
`+` = match 1 *or more* of the previous expression
`{n,m}` = match at least *n* but not more than *m* occurrences.
`{n,}` = match at least *n* and unlimited times.

Simple:

```
str1.replace(/\|+/g, "|")
"|a|jump|fences|in the street"
```

Matches one or more pipes and replaces with a single pipe. This replaces a single pipe with a pipe.

More exact:

```
str1.replace(/\|{2,}/g, "|")
"|a|jump|fences|in the street"
```

Matches two *or more* (because there is no max after the comma) pipes and replaces with a single pipe.  This does not bother replacing a single pipe with another single pipe.

There are also a couple of ways to match *exactly* two pipes, if you'll never have a run of 3 or more:

```
str1.replace(/\|\|/, "|");
str1.replace(/\|{2}/, "|");
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen for the explanation. I have been added for a few hours now and I could not grasp why it was not working. I'm sincerely humbled and appreciative.

Answer (score 2):

Not much to it:
`\|\|+` replace with `|`

https://regex101.com/r/vvkrI0/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `+` to find all the locations that have 1 or more pipes in a row, and replace them all with a single pipe. Your regex would simply be:

```
/\|+/g
```

Here is an example, with a variable number of pipes:

```js
const str1 = "||a|||jump|fences||||in the street";
var filtered_str1 = str1.replace(/\|+/g,"|")
console.log(filtered_str1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could substitute consective pipe characters like this:

```
const pat = /\|{2,}/gm;
const str = `||a|||jump|fences||in the street`;
const sub = `|`;

const res = str.replace(pat, sub);
console.log('result: ', res);
```

Result:

```
|a|jump|fences|in the street
```